# Java/Eclipse: How is it possible to make an event appear/happen at the users onscreen tap/click location?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, coordinates

Good afternoon
I have been learning and loving java for eclipse to try to make a fun little app game. Its coming along really well and I use this site often because its **really** helpful.
One thing I'm stuck on and couldn't find help for anywhere was this situation,

I have a series of enemies as ImageButtons and have certain onclick events based on if they are visible or which other game events are currently going on, no problem so far.

One of these enemies will explode when the player taps them so I added another image *(another image because it is larger and slightly off center)* over the top of it and have at least 20 around the place for the various enemies to be toggled on quickly to "appear" that the enemy has exploded.
This quickly mounts up to alot of messy images onscreen, and alot of resources being used (unnessecerily I think)

This is where the optimisation comes in. If I can have one image, and one event to capture where the person clicked and teleport that image to there (and learn the foundations of the code to make dynamic events happen on click locations) I will be able to get rid of all the overlaying "explosions" and just have one central one which teleports?

How can I make it so something like this happens:

```
on click screen
get x, get y coordinates.
if(x and y are in appropriate places on screen){
teleport image to this x,y / make image appear at this x,y / do predefined event at x,y
}
```

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `OnTouchListener.onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)` or override `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // do something;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // do something;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // do something;
            break;
        default:
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @ataulm my bad. :( Somehow that text came into the answer. didnt notice it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setOnTouchListener`. It will listen that the touch is going to be happen on the screen.

Hope it might help.